# Getting a error no :-101 ,code :ESOCKET in node js while doing task with nodemailer api

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am kinda sending mails using the nodemailer API . Here is my code for creating SMPT Transport .

```
// Creating the SMPT transport
const mailConfigure = {
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.GUSER,
    pass: process.env.GPASS,
  },
};
```

And the error i'am  getting is

Error: connect ENETUNREACH 74.125.68.109:465
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
errno: -101,
code: 'ESOCKET',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '74.125.68.109',
port: 465,
command: 'CONN'
}

I also have tried changing the port number and setting secure to false still getting this error . Guys Help me out ....

Comment: Do you understand what ENETUNREACH means?  Can you ping smtp.gmail.com? (if that happens to be 74.125.68.109 still)  Your internet connection may be unstable.